# Selecting data from the database based on one of the values

Tags: python, sql, psql

I don't know SQL well. You need to get all the values about the client for one or more requested data. A user can have several phone numbers.

The correct First Name\Last Name\email is displayed here, but the wrong phone number, specifically the first id in the list, but not belonging to the client. If without LIMIT 1, all phone numbers in the database will be displayed.

```
def find_client(cur, name=None, lastname=None, email=None, phone=None):
    cur.execute("""SELECT cl.name, cl.lastname, cl.email, pn.number FROM clients cl, PhoneNumber pn
                 WHERE  pn.client_id = cl.id 
                 AND cl.name=%s OR cl.lastname=%s OR cl.email=%s OR pn.number=%s;                
                 """, (name,lastname,email,phone))
    return cur.fetchall()
```

Comment: Is USER and CLIENT the same thing? You used both terms here, but that's confusing. Also, if a client can have several phone numbers, then which do you want to return? Also, update your from and join to `from clients cl join phonenumber pn on cl.id = pn.client_id` because your current code is very antiquated.

Answer (score 0):

I very much prefer using an explicit join rather than the old style join you have.  This removes the join logic from the rest of the WHERE clause conditions.
Your version has a mix of ANDs and ORs and is likely failing because of the questionable boolean logic.
Try this SQL instead:

```
SELECT cl.name,
   cl.lastname,
   cl.email,
   pn.number
FROM   clients cl
   left join phonenumber pn
          ON pn.client_id = cl.id
WHERE  cl.name =% s
    OR cl.lastname =% s
    OR cl.email =% s
    OR pn.number =% s
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you need to differentiate AND and OR using '(' ')'
Can use the following...
cur.execute("""SELECT cl.name, cl.lastname, cl.email, pn.number FROM clients cl,
PhoneNumber pn WHERE  pn.client_id = cl.id AND
(cl.name=%s OR cl.lastname=%s OR cl.email=%s OR pn.number=%s);""",
(name,lastname,email,phone))